# Корзина ajax не работает при подгрузке формы функцией load

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, есть корзина на ajax

```
<form action="" id="form1" method="post">
<input name="name" type="hidden" value="Название" />
<input name="price" type="hidden" value="5000" />
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="5" />
<button class="cart">Купить</button>
</form>
```

и скрипт

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cart").click(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var id = parent.children()[0].value;
            var name = parent.children()[1].value;
            var price = parent.children()[2].value;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/add_to_cart/",
                data: {id: id,name: name, price:price},
                success: function(data){$(".cart").attr('disabled','disabled').html('Добавлено');}
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Все работает, но не работает в том случаи если я форму подгружаю функцией load. в чем может быть дело?

P.S. Jquery ajax только учу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cart").live('click',function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var id = parent.children()[0].value;
            var name = parent.children()[1].value;
            var price = parent.children()[2].value;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/add_to_cart/",
                data: {id: id,name: name, price:price},
                success: function(data){$(".cart").attr('disabled','disabled').html('Добавлено');}
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```